# how to remove footerview from recyclerview when don't need load more item?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

you can check my code as below:

```
private class ContentListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    public static final int TYPE_ITEM = 0;
    public static final int TYPE_FOOTER = 1;

    private ArrayList<BookSearchModel.BookSearchVO> itemList    = null;

    public ContentListAdapter(ArrayList<BookSearchModel.BookSearchVO> item) {
        itemList = item;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if(position >= itemList.size()) {
            return TYPE_FOOTER;
        }

        return TYPE_ITEM;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        if(viewType == TYPE_ITEM)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)wrapperContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View item = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lib_book_search_item, parent, false);

            return new BookInfoHolder(item);
        }
        else
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)wrapperContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View item = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_footer, parent, false);

            return new FooterViewHolder(item);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder wrappedHolder, int position) {
        if(wrappedHolder instanceof BookInfoHolder) {
            SOME OF VIEW BIND PROCESS....
        } else if(wrappedHolder instanceof FooterViewHolder) {
            // do nothing.
        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return itemList.size() + 1;
    }

    public class BookInfoHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private ImageView bookCover;
        private TextView bookTitle;
        private TextView bookAuthor;
        private TextView bookPublisher;
        private TextView bookLocation;

        public BookInfoHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            bookCover       = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.book_cover);
            bookTitle       = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.book_title);
            bookAuthor      = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.book_author_info);
            bookPublisher   = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.book_publisher);
            bookLocation    = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.book_location);
        }
    }

    public class FooterViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private View v;

        public FooterViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            this.v = itemView;
        }
    }
}
```

i tried `RecyclerView.removeViewAt(position)`
it casues null pointer exception, i guess recycler's child view not similar to listview.
and, i tried to use layoutmanager, but i have no idea for layoutmanager control childView(or item).

and noted this: [Remove RecyclerView FooterView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33982271/remove-recyclerview-footerview)
but, any other doesn't work for me.

if load all of item, how can i remove footerView?

**EDIT:**

[what i see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hYcqP.png)

[what i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N0BW9.png)

**lib_book_search_item.xml**

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="135dp"
            android:id="@+id/book_cover"
            android:transitionName="@string/book_cover_transition"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:paddingTop="3dp"
            android:paddingBottom="3dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:id="@+id/book_title"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textColor="#929292"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:paddingTop="3dp"
            android:paddingBottom="3dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:id="@+id/book_author_info"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textColor="#929292"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:paddingTop="3dp"
            android:paddingBottom="3dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:id="@+id/book_publisher"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textColor="#01A997"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:paddingTop="3dp"
            android:paddingBottom="3dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:id="@+id/book_location"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textColor="#3C7FED"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:paddingTop="3dp"
            android:paddingBottom="3dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:id="@+id/book_status"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="#CCCCCC"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**list_footer.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="24dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:text="@string/msg_loading_data"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You could make the view's visiblity to `GONE`

Comment: i have added the answer please check.. update if it works.. !! @JYL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass the **max_items** of your list.

`max_items` = *Total items after the list is fully formed after all items are added*.

```
  public ContentListAdapter(ArrayList<BookSearchModel.BookSearchVO> item, int max_items) {
    itemList = item;
    this.max_items = max_items;
   }
```

Then in your `onBindViewHolder` do this checking.

```
    else if(wrappedHolder instanceof FooterViewHolder) {
        // do nothing.
        if(position == max_items){

          wrappedHolder.rootLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE); // this will remove the footer..
       }
    }
```

Comment: I think it looks like working well. i ll feedback after test that code. thanks

Comment: i checked this code. bottom footerview removed well, 
but still remain whitespace what is footerview was been occupied.  rcvList.measure will it help?

Comment: u are making it **gone**  ...not **invisible** it should remove the white space too.. can you post a screenshot..you are making the whole item gone ryt ?? @JYL

Comment: i attach my screenshot. 'what i see' is scroll to bottom whitespace   'what i want' is scrolled limit last item position.

Comment: post your `lib_book_search_item.xml` @JYL

Comment: sorry post your `list_footer` .xml @JYL

Comment: i have updated please check...initialize your footer root layout(in your FooterViewHolder)..make it gone ..instead of itemView @JYL

Comment: i add xml too. in xml has problem?

Comment: ok i am exlaining.., in `list_footer` you have linear layout at top...so find the linearLayout in FooterViewHolder like `itemView.findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);` and set it gone ..instead of `wrapperHolder.itemView` use `wrappedHolder.linearLayout(Gone)` its easy....ask if you didnt understand.. @JYL

Comment: and also remove fixed height from the linearLayout instead of `100dp` make it `wrap_content` @JYL

Comment: hmm.. i add **this.v = itemView.findViewById(R.id.footer_root);** int FooterViewHolder and add id(footer_root) for **list_footer.xml**'s linearLayout, and call **((FooterViewHolder)wrappedHolder).v.setVisibility(View.GONE);** but not working.                                                                                       i'm very thank you but It 's three o'clock in the morning.. i have to go sleep for today's office job.. i'm sorry to despite of your effort but that was not solved. But I have a good idea so I'll let you know if the problem is solved.

Comment: and btw did your remove `100dp` height of linearlayout to `wrap_content` ?? @JYL

Comment: yep. i did. maybe recyclerview h eight not refreshed.

Comment: inform me tomorrow ,if i find out something..i will let you know tomorrow @JYL

Comment: I have solved the problem by referring to this example: http://android-pratap.blogspot.kr/2015/06/endless-recyclerview-with-progress-bar.html  it makes a little different what i expect, but i satisfied about that.